# Series as columns in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to render at very basic column chart where each series is on column in itself.
I can almost make it work if it set each column inside series[].data
Here is a jsFiddle where the bars are correct but the legend should show the same as the column names (Alla and company).

https://jsfiddle.net/rsL1tza2/

```
series: [{
        data: [{
            name: 'Alla',
            y: 76.9,
            color: '#003960'
        },
        {
            name: 'Company',
            y: 77.2,
            color: '#006bb6'
        }]
    }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current data structure only specifies a single series.

You need to move your `series` properties out of the `data` array, and specify them as two separate series, like this:

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Alla',
    color: '#003960',
    data: [76.9]
  }, {
    name: 'Company',
    color: '#006bb6',
    data: [77.2]
  }]
```

This may cause other issues with the x axis label that you may want to address, but that's a different issue.

Example:

- https://jsfiddle.net/rsL1tza2/1/

Although, if your data is actually this simple, it is far better for usability to label the bars directly on the x axis, rather than in a legend, where the user must look back and forth from the legend to the bars and match up the colors.  FWIW.

**EDIT**

If you want the series name to appear in both the axis labels and the legend, you need to do things a little different.

1) Set `grouping` to false in your `plotOptions`

2) Specify your `categories`, or set the `name` in both the `series` properties, and the `data` point

3) specify an `x` value for each data point.

Axis:

```
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Alla', 'Company'],
  }
```

Plot Options:

```
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      grouping: false
    }
  }
```

Series:

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Alla',
    color: '#003960',
    data: [[0,76.9]]
  }, {
    name: 'Company',
    color: '#006bb6',
    data: [[1,77.2]]
  }]
```

Fiddle:

- https://jsfiddle.net/rsL1tza2/4/

Comment: This sadly gives to exact problem with the xAxis missing the series as labels (instead of just 0)

Comment: Right, as I mentioned. You didn't ask about x axis labels though, you asked about series and legend :)  You'll need to be more specific about exactly what you want to accomplish. Also, I have to question why you would want x axis labels that are duplicated in a legend. The legend is completely unnecessary  if you label the axis. In the vast majority of cases, doing this as one series with no legend, and properly labeled x axis categories is the best way to display your data. But regardless - be explicit in what you need, and we can solve it.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly there seems to be some issues with tooltip and hiding columns. I need them to be in the legend to enable people to hide the columns. This is an existing chart that I need to duplicate in highcharts and it needs to look the same :)

Comment: The tooltip code was from your original example :) Here is an update without any tooltip details or point events specified: https://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/rsL1tza2/6/

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep `name` out of `data` field:

https://jsfiddle.net/0kfmqnu4/

```
series: [{
        name: 'Alla',
        data: [76.9]
    }, {
        name: 'Company',
        data: [77.2]
    }]
```

Comment: That does not seem to add the series names on the xAxis line